# как сделать конкатенацию строк?

Tags: c#

есть метод modelValue который принимает model animals и я хочу чтобы это метод сделал конкатенацию тех значений который находятся в (Name, Age),как это сделать?

```
public class Animals
    {
       public string Name {get; set;}
       public string Age {get; set;}
       public string LastName{get; set;}
       public string Number{get; set;}
    }

public string modelValue(Animals animals)
{

}
```

Comment: Взять Name, Age и сложить. Что по вашему конкатенация?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string modelValue(Animals animals)
        {
            return animals.Name + animals.Age;
        }
```

Comment: например этот метод примет друй модель , мне надо сделать так чтобы этот метод работал для всех моделей

Comment: создайте абстрактный класс и на следуйте от него и используйте override для каждого метода

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вам просто надо собрать значения всех свойств модели и вас скорость работы не беспокоит, то можно вот так попробовать

```
public string modelValue<T>(T input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var p in typeof(T).GetProperties().OrderBy(x=>x.Name))
        sb.AppendLine($"{p.Name} = {p.GetValue(input)}");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Тогда для класса

```
public class Animals
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Вот такой вызов

```
Console.WriteLine(
        modelValue(
            new Animals() {Age = "18", Name = "Vasya", LastName = "Pupkin", Number = "1"}));
```

Напечатает вот это

```
Age = 18
LastName = Pupkin
Name = Vasya
Number = 1
```